# Obtain corresponding value to max value of another column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to find the corresponding value to the max value of another column.

My data is as below:

| group | subgroup | subgroup_2 | value_a | value_b | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 101 | 1 | 200 | 101 | 20220301 |
| A | 102 | 1 | 105 | 90 | 20220301 |
| A | 103 | 2 | 90 | 202 | 20220301 |
| A | 211 | 2 | 75 | 107 | 20220301 |
| B | 212 | 1 | 91 | 65 | 20220301 |
| B | 213 | 1 | 175 | 101 | 20220301 |

I would need to format the data like this:

| group | subgroup_2 | max_value_a | value_b | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 200 | 101 | 20220301 |
| A | 2 | 90 | 202 | 20220301 |
| B | 1 | 175 | 101 | 20220301 |

I can achieve the format fairly easily via a group by, however I have to aggregate value_b to do this which doesn't give me the result I need.

I know I can use rank() over partition by but it doesn't seem to provide the format I require.

This is the query I used below, however it only provides the max of one subgroup_2 rather than the max of each:

```
select group, subgroup_2, max_value_a, value_b, date
from
(
select a.group, a.subgroup_2, a.max_value_a, a.value_b, a.date,
       rank() over(partition by a.group, subgroup_2, a.date order by a.max_value_a desc) as rnk
  from table_1 a
)s
where rnk=1
```

Comment: Your rank's partition is wrong and should only include `group` and `subgroup_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
SELECT group, subgroup_2, value_a AS max_value_a, value_b, date
FROM
(
    SELECT group, subgroup_2, value_a, value_b, date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group, subgroup_2 ORDER BY value_a DESC) rn
    FROM table_1
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. When I use MAX() over I end up with multiple entries from subgroup_2 all with max _value_a and corresponding value_b. I'm looking for one entry per subgroup_2

Comment: I guess I didn't read the question very closely.  I think you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` here.